# Question regarding collapsable content with html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking around on some collapsables, most of them seem to use some extra code that doesn't seem to be needed or I can't understand haha.
anyways, I made a super simple one and in my mind and logic it SHOULD work. but apparently it gets the error of

```
app.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at btn (app.js:4)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:9)
```

if someone would be so kind to properly explain to me WHY this isn't working so I might understand the logic better?
here is snippet:

```js
var content = document.querySelector(".content");
function btn(){
  if (content.style.display === "none") {
    content.style.display = "block";
  } else {
  content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="btn();">collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p> inner content bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance! /Thuse

Comment: you dont have any element with ID of content

Comment: Change `getElementById("content");` to `querySelector(".content");` You use content class every where but are programming the javascript to look for the id.

Comment: You can use the native `datails` element for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: thanks guys, long day of practice coding and was staring myself blind on stuff i should know. for taking ur time to help +rep

Comment: Your new code seems working except that you need to use `none` instead of `block` again in else condition. preferably move that querySeelector inside the function and not above the html codes as a global variable. @Thuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have assigned a class name to that element so use querySelector instead of ID selector:

```
var content = document.querySelector(".content");
```

Please note that querySelectot returns the first occurance of a query. So if you have multiple elements you will need `(querySelectorAll(".blah"))[x]` to select the Xth element.

As a JQuery fan, using JQuery you just need 1 line of code:

```
function btn(){
    $(".content").toggle()
}
```